# Java : Retrieve Column names from ResultSet

Tags: java, metadata, resultset

I would like to get the columns name from the ResultSet returned from the call of a stored procedure.

```
cstmt = c.prepareCall("CALL MyProcedure(?,?,?)");
ArrayDescriptor descriptionArrayString = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TYPE_TABLEAU_CHAINES", c);
ARRAY arrayNumfics = new ARRAY(descriptionArrayString, c, numfics.toArray());
cstmt.setArray(1, arrayNumfics);
cstmt.setDouble(2, offreId);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.ARRAY, "TYPE_TABLEAU_OBJ");         

cstmt.executeUpdate();

java.sql.Array arrayObjects = cstmt.getArray(3);
ResultSet rs = arrayObjects .getResultSet();
int i = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
    STRUCT structure = ((STRUCT) rs.getObject(2));

    if(i == 0) {
        StructDescriptor descriptor = structure.getDescriptor();
        ResultSetMetaData metadata  = descriptor.getMetaData();
        int numAttrs = descriptor.getLength(); 

        System.out.println("descriptor length = " + numAttrs);
        System.out.println("Number of columns = " + metadata.getColumnCount());

        for (int j = 1; j <= metadata.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            String name = metadata.getColumnName(j);

            System.out.println("Column Name " + j + " = " + name);
        }
    }

    Object elements[] = structure.getAttributes();

    System.out.println("obj[0] = " + elements[0]);
    System.out.println("obj[1] = " + elements[1]);
    System.out.println("obj[2] = " + elements[2]);

    i++;
}
```

This is what is displayed :

```
descriptor length = 15
Number of columns = 15
```

But when I call metadata.getColumnName(j) with j = 1, I have this error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403 No Data Found
```

---

Stored procedure

```
PROCEDURE myprocedure (param1 IN TYPE_TABLEAU_CHAINES, param2 IN NUMBER,
param3 OUT TYPE_TABLEAU_OBJ) AS

TYPE myRecord IS RECORD (
name1 VARCHAR2(11),
name2 VARCHAR2(6),
name3 VARCHAR2(11),
name4 VARCHAR2(11),
name5 VARCHAR2(11),
name6 DATE,
name7 VARCHAR2(13),
name8 VARCHAR2(2),
name9 VARCHAR2(4),
name10 VARCHAR2(32),
name11 VARCHAR2(32),
name12 VARCHAR2(15),
name13 VARCHAR2(38),
name14 VARCHAR2(4),
name15 VARCHAR2(3)
);

TYPE typeCursor IS REF CURSOR;

mysigREC myRecord ;
mysigOBJ TYPE_MYOBJECT;
i NUMBER := 1;
queryString VARCHAR2(10000) := '';
myCursor typeCursor;

BEGIN
    mysigOBJ := TYPE_TABLEAU_SIGNALEMENTS();
    queryString := 'SELECT name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7,
    name8, name9, name10, name11, name12, name13, name14, name15 FROM
    TSIGGRC WHERE name22 = ''VALUE''';

    OPEN myCursor FOR queryString;
    LOOP
        FETCH myCursor INTO mysigREC ;
        EXIT WHEN myCursor%NOTFOUND;
        mysigOBJ := new TYPE_MYOBJECT();
        mysigOBJ .set_name1(mysigREC .name1);
        mysigOBJ .set_name2(mysigREC .name2);
        mysigOBJ .set_name3(mysigREC .name3);
        mysigOBJ .set_name4(mysigREC .name4);
        mysigOBJ .set_name5(mysigREC .name5);
        mysigOBJ .set_name6(mysigREC .name6);
        mysigOBJ .set_name7(mysigREC .name7);
        mysigOBJ .set_name8(mysigREC .name8);
        mysigOBJ .set_name9(mysigREC .name9);
        mysigOBJ .set_name10(mysigREC .name10);
        mysigOBJ .set_name11(mysigREC .name11);
        mysigOBJ .set_name12(mysigREC .name12);
        mysigOBJ .set_name13(mysigREC .name13);
        mysigOBJ .set_name14(mysigREC .name14);
        mysigOBJ .set_name15(mysigREC .name15);

        param3 .EXTEND();
        param3 (i) := mysigOBJ ;
        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;

END myProcedure;
```

Comment: I think it would help if you also included the definition of the stored procedure.

Comment: OK, I think that SQL ARRAYs do not have column names. What is the reason for retrieving data that way anyway? Why not have the stored procedure return the result set directly, not via one of its parameters?

Comment: No it did work when the result was one column only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it.

I changed the PLSQL Type TYPE_MYOBJECT before and I did not give again the grant to the user of the application. That is the reason why it says "No data found".

Just doing the :

```
grant execute on TYPE_MYOBJ to USER_OF_APPLICATION;
```

solves the problem.